# 404 Not found localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I made app with Node.js , Express, React and MongoDB.
I completed Redux store setup in Client side and want to create action to get data for cars data from MongoDB for Node.js.

I created new file action:

carsAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getAllCars=()=> async dispatch=>{
    dispatch({type: 'LOADING', payload: true})

    try{
        const response = await axios.get('/api/cars/getallcars');
        dispatch({type: 'GET_ALL_CARS', payload: response.data});
        dispatch({type: 'LOADING' , payload: false});
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch({type: 'LOADING', payload: false});
    }
}
```

After that I created alertReducer.js for loading

```
const initialData = {
    loading: false
};

export const alertsReducer = (state=initialData, action)=> {
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'LOADING' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading : action.payload
            }
        }
        default : return state ;
    }
}
```

After that I add alertsReducer in store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware , combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { carsReducer } from './reducers/carReducer';
import { alertsReducer } from './reducers/alertsReducer';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({});

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    carsReducer,
    alertsReducer
});

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

export default store
```

I added and proxy in packege.json in client side:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

And in home file I added function with useeffect and dispatcher. I had problems with useEffect for that there is dispatch inside useEffect and I write it so:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from '../components/DefaultLayout'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllCars } from '../redux/actions/carsActions'

function Home() {
    const {cars} = useSelector(state=> state.carsReducer)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(()=>{
      dispatch(getAllCars())

    }, [dispatch]);

      return (
        <DefaultLayout>
          
          <h1>Home Page</h1>
          <h1>The length of cars array is {cars.length}</h1>

        </DefaultLayout>
      )
}

export default Home
```

And In end , I want the app show me how much cars it has, how I wrote in Home file, but in the console of the browser there is error after load localhost:3000 in the browser:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/cars/getallcars 404 (Not Found)
```

I checked link: Localhost:5000/api/cars/getallcars and it loads cars data in json in browser.

Comment: Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Then do `npm install` again.. Most likely this is the issue with caching which would be solved when you recraete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`